# Efficient way of counting number of matching objects within an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

please see attempt and examples below, I am looking for an efficient way in JS to get the number of fruits matched. Currently I am using filter to find matches within `items` array, but I am wondering if there is a better approach **(without having to filter through the `fruits` array on each iteration ~ imagining it is a much bigger array of fruits)**.

```
  const items = [
    {
      id: '111',
      name: 'apple',
    },
    {
      id: '222',
      name: 'apple',
    },
    {
      id: '333',
      name: 'kiwi',
    },
  ];

  const fruits = [
    {
      id: 'fruit-1',
      name: 'apple',
    },
    {
      id: 'fruit-2',
      name: 'banana',
    },
    {
      id: 'fruit-3',
      name: 'kiwi',
    },
  ];

  // attempted
  const numberOfFruitsInItems = fruits.map((fruit) => {
    const itemsWithFruit = items.filter(({ name }) => fruit.name === name);

    return {
      ...fruit,
      total: itemsWithFruit.length,
    };
  });

  console.log(numberOfFruitsInItems);

  // desired response
  [
    {
      id: 'fruit-1',
      name: 'apple',
      total: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 'fruit-2',
      name: 'banana',
      total: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 'fruit-3',
      name: 'kiwi',
      total: 1,
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate the `fruits` array with a count, or create a new array of objects with the count info?

Comment: Ideally it should not mutate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in **one** iteration over `items` that updates a global counter of corresponding fruit.

```
// Use a hashed object to keep count of totals per fruit name.
// totals[FRUIT NAME] = ...number of items having name=FRUIT NAME
const totals = {}

// Fill the totals hash in one single iteration of items
items.forEach(item => {
  totals[item.name] = (totals[item.name] || 0) + 1
})

const numberOfFruitsInItems = fruits.map((fruit) => {
  return {
    ...fruit,
    total: totals[fruit.name] || 0,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As many questions and answers on this site, you should group the array of objects by `name`, counting each and storing in a `grouped` object with keys that are names and values that are count.

```js
const items = [{id:"111",name:"apple"},{id:"222",name:"apple"},{id:"333",name:"kiwi"},];
const fruits = [{id:"fruit-1",name:"apple"},{id:"fruit-2",name:"banana"},{id:"fruit-3",name:"kiwi"},];

var grouped = items.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.name] = (agg[item.name] || 0) + 1
  return agg
}, {})

fruits.forEach(function(item) {
  item.total = grouped[item.name] || 0
})

console.log(fruits)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cache the item frequencies before your map each of the fruits.

```js
const
  items = [
    { id: '111', name: 'apple' },
    { id: '222', name: 'apple' },
    { id: '333', name: 'kiwi' }
  ],
  fruits = [
    { id: 'fruit-1', name: 'apple' },
    { id: 'fruit-2', name: 'banana' },
    { id: 'fruit-3', name: 'kiwi' }
  ];

const main = () => {
  const reducedFruits = fruitReducer(fruits, items);
  console.log(reducedFruits);
};

const computeFrequency = (items, accessor) =>
  items.reduce((acc, item) =>
    (key =>
      acc.set(key, (acc.get(key) ?? 0) + 1))
    (accessor ? accessor(item) : item), new Map);

const fruitReducer = (fruits, items) =>
  ((freqMap) =>
    fruits.map(({ id, name }) =>
      ({ id, name, total: freqMap.get(name) ?? 0 })))
  (computeFrequency(items, ({ name }) => name))

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to separate out the two mechanisms to remove the nested iteration. First iterate over the `items` array using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a dictionary of key/value pairs (e.g. `{ apple: 2 }`, and *then* loop over the `fruits` array adding in the correct count information from the dictionary.

```js
const items=[{id:"111",name:"apple"},{id:"222",name:"apple"},{id:"333",name:"kiwi"}],fruits=[{id:"fruit-1",name:"apple"},{id:"fruit-2",name:"banana"},{id:"fruit-3",name:"kiwi"}];

// `reduce` over the items.
// If the item name isn't a key on the object
// set it to zero, then add one
const itemCount = items.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
  fruits[name] ??= 0;
  ++fruits[name];
  return fruits;
}, {});

// Update the `fruits` using the dictionary
// count information - note this mutates the
// `fruits` array so if you want a new array
// use `map` instead of `forEach`
fruits.forEach(fruit => {
  fruit.count = itemCount[fruit.name] || 0;
});

console.log(fruits);
```

Additional information

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

A version which does not mutate your original data -- after all, we're not barbarians, right? -- could start by creating copies of your `fruit` array, adding a `count` property to each, storing them as an object keyed off the fruit name, then folding the `items` list into it by incrementing the `count` property of the relevant node.  At the end, we just collect and return the `values` of this object.

The code is pretty simple:

```js
const countFruits = (fruits, items) => Object .values (items .reduce (
  (a, {name}) => ((a [name] .count += 1), a),
  fruits .reduce ((a, f) => ((a [f .name] = {...f , count: 0}), a), {})
))

const items = [{id: '111', name: 'apple'}, {id: '222', name: 'apple'}, {id: '333', name: 'kiwi'}]
const fruits = [{id: 'fruit-1', name: 'apple', }, {id: 'fruit-2', name: 'banana', }, {id: 'fruit-3', name: 'kiwi', }]

console .log (countFruits (fruits, items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that there is no error-checking, and you may need it.  What if `items` included `{id" 444', name: 'papaya'}`, even though `paypaya` was not in the list of fruits.  This should not be too hard to handle, and we can leave it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const fruits = [
    { Apple: 4, Orange: 7, Grape: 3 },
    { Guava: 6, Lemon: 4, Banana: 8 },
    { Orange: 5, Pineapple: 7, Apple: 7 },
  ];

  let fruitCount = {};

  fruits.forEach((item) => {
    for (let fruit in item) {
      if (fruitCount[fruit]) {
        fruitCount[fruit] = fruitCount[fruit] + item[fruit];
      } else {
        fruitCount[fruit] = item[fruit];
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(fruitCount);
```